# Finding columns with same value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of books in SQL. I am interested in finding the names of the books with same price. How can i achieve this?

[View of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmgAM.png)

So according to this table it should give me c and d since both of them have price value of 1000. However i am not able to do so. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the table to it self and have the price as join criteria.

Something like

```
select distinct a.* 
  from book as a
  join book as b on (a.price = b.price)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72eef1/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select price,group_concat(title)
from books
group by price having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return your expected result as the title of the price which are same:

```
SELECT title 
FROM book
WHERE price IN (
  SELECT price
  FROM book 
  GROUP BY price
  HAVING COUNT(price) > 1
 )
```

[**Demo on SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/176ddd/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Group_concat(title) 
FROM   books 
GROUP  BY price 
HAVING Count(*) >= 2;
```

[Demo on Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2f4bf/1)